# The Matlab equivalent of Python's "None"

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a keyword in Matlab that is roughly equivalent to `None` in python?

I am trying to use it to mark an optional argument to a function. I am translating the following Python code

```
def f(x,y=None):
    if y == None:
        return g(x)
    else:
        return h(x,y)
```

into Matlab

```
function rtrn = f(x,y)
    if y == []:
        rtrn = g(x);
    else
        rtrn = h(x,y);
    end;
end
```

As you can see currently I am using `[]` as `None`. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to do in Matlab?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

in your specific case. you may use `nargin` to determine how many input arguments here provided when calling the function.

from the [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html#br67di7-1):

> The nargin and nargout functions
>   enable you to determine how many input
>   and output arguments a function is
>   called with. You can then use
>   conditional statements to perform
>   different tasks depending on the
>   number of arguments. For example,

```
function c = testarg1(a, b) 
     if (nargin == 1)
         c = a .^ 2; 
     elseif (nargin == 2)
         c = a + b; 
     end
```

> Given a single input argument, this
>   function squares the input value.
>   Given two inputs, it adds them
>   together.

Comment: I'd also add another else step in the if loop to catch the cases where the function is called with the incorrect number of input arguments, you could then flag this as an error

Answer (score 12):

`NaN` while not equivalent, often serves the similar purpose.

Comment: `NaN` does not server the same purpose as `None` in Python. `NaN` means that an error occurred in a numerical computation. It is a value that can be used as a flag for "not given", but so is `0` or `[]` or `{}` or `'none'` or any other value you'd like to choose. The equivalent in MATLAB to passing `None` is not passing a value at all, which can be detected as shown in some of the other answers here.

Answer (score 7):

`nargin` is definitely the easiest way of doing it. Also it is usually good practice to validate the number of input argument using **[nargchk](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargchk.html)**:

```matlab
function e = testFunc(a,b,c,d)
    error( nargchk(2, 4, nargin, 'struct') );

    % set default values
    if nargin<4, d = 0; end
    if nargin<3, c = 0; end

    % ..
    c = a*b + c*d;

end
```

... which acts as a way to ensure the correct number of arguments is passed. In this case, a minimum of *two* arguments are required, with a maximum of *four*.

If `nargchk` detects no error, execution resumes normally, otherwise an error is generated. For example, calling `testFunc(1)` generates:

```
Not enough input arguments.
```

> UPDATE: A new function was introduced in R2011b [`narginchk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/narginchk.html), which replaces the use of the deprecated `nargchk`+`error` seen above:
>
> ```
> narginchk(2,4);
> ```

You can use functions like: **[exist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html)** and **[isempty](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html)**  to check whether a variable exists and whether it is empty respectively:

```matlab
if ~exist('c','var') || isempty(c)
  c = 10;
end
```

which allows you to call your function such as: `testFunc(1,2,[],4)` telling it to use the default value for `c` but still giving a value for `d`

You could also use **[varargin](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html)** to accept a variable number of arguments.

Finally a powerful way to parse and validate named inputs is to use **[inputParser](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html)**

To see examples and other alternatives of passing arguments and setting default values, check out [this post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/05/05/nice-way-to-set-function-defaults/) and its comments as well.

Comment: Since then, a new function was introduced [`narginchk`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/narginchk.html) which replaces the use of the deprecated `nargchk`+`error` seen above

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent to Python `None` in MATLAB is `string(missing)`

To test, type the following in your command window : `py.type( string(missing) )`

It returns `<class 'NoneType'>`

`MATLAB` to `python` data types documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html)

If you want to pass `None` into a `Python` function that you are calling from `MATLAB`, then you would pass in `string(missing)`. This argument would show up as `None` in the `Python` function, for example, if you are detecting for `None` such as `if arg1 == None`.

Comment: But `string(missing)` is a 1x1 string array, not exactly the same as `None`. `len(None)` in Python errors out, for example, whereas `length(string(missing))` is 1 in MATLAB. `isempty(string(missing))` is false, and you can't convert to a boolean (`if None:` in Python works, `if string(missing)` in MATLAB doesn't).

Comment: I see what you mean, however, in some of my Python functions, I detect whether some of my arguments are None or not and take action accordingly. If I want to pass None to indicate one of those conditions while calling the function from Matlab, then I can do so with string(missing). MATLAB documentation : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/passing-data-to-python.html

Comment: That's a really good point!