# How to check whether an argument is supplied in function call?

Tags: matlab

Say that I have a function, `dummy`, with 2 arguments. The arguments can have default values when not supplied in function call. But how do I know is an arguments is not supplied?

I know I can use `nargin`, like this

```
function dummy(arg1, arg2)
if nargin < 2
    arg2 = 0;
end
if nargin < 1
    arg1 = 0;
end
% function body
```

I want to know whether I can check whether an arguments is supplied based on the argument name? Something like `supplied(arg2) == false`.

I ask this because, sometimes I want to add new arguments at the front of the argument list (as it may not have a default value), and then I have to change all the `if nargin ...`. If I can check by name, nothing has to be changed.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I always do like that:

```
if ~exist('arg1','var')
  arg1=0;
end
```

As said by @Andrey, with this solution you can change the number/order of the arguments of the function, without changing the code. This is not the case with the `nargin` solution.

As said by @yuk, if you want to allow to skip arguments you can do:

```
if ~exist('arg1','var') || isempty(arg1)
  arg1=arg1DefaultValue;
end
```

Comment: This is much better than nargin, because you don't have to change the code in case you ever change the order of the parameters in the function.

Comment: I usually also add `... | isempty(arg1)`, so user can skip `arg1`, but supply `arg2`. Of course if `arg1` cannot be empty.

Comment: Abosultely, but I thought it was not really answering the question. Anyway, I edited the answer, Also I think you have to use `||` (Short-Circuit Operator) to make sure there is no error if `arg1` does not exist.

Comment: Note that skipping here means supplying `[]` or `{}` in place of the argument, not the Visual Basic / VBScript style skipping, where one places multiple commas like this `f(,,a,,,a)`.