# Passing variable sized arguments to a method

Tags: matlab

I'm using the PrintTable method of the [matlabtools](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52299-kermor-matlabtools). In the documentation the following example is given:

```
t = PrintTable('LaTeX/PDF export demo, %s',datestr(now));
t.HasRowHeader = true;
t.HasHeader = true;
t.addRow('A','B','C');
```

Let's say I have the header names in a cell array `header = {'A','B','C'}`. Unfortunately a cell array cannot be passed to `addRow`, i.e. `t.addRow(header);` does not work. Unfortunately the size of the header varies in my case, that's why I'm storing it in a cell array.

How can I call the `addRow` method with a variable sized cell array?

Comment: You should convert `header` to a comma separated list: `t.addRow(header{:});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways. The second way would be more elegant in the script but the first way is more functional as you can create the cell using code and can still call it in your script. In the second way, you can't do that.

- Encapsulate what you have in a cell (i.e. 1 variable): `t.addRow({'A', 'B', 'C'})` and your function `addRow` would just ask about the length of the cell and proceed accordingly.
- Use optional args [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764062/optional-args-in-matlab-functions)