# How to make this function work despite the fact that a parameter is empty?

Tags: matlab

I have the following loop :

```
for i=1:size(voisins1_TSP,1)
    cout(i)=CalculCost(voisins1_TSP(i,:),voisins1_Indexes(i,:),voisins1_Star(i,:),ring_costs,star_costs);
end
```

However, `voisins1_Star(i,:)` can be empty and MATLAB is not happy with that:

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
>    Error in `Mainipulation` (line 38)
>
> ```
> cout(i)=CalculCost(voisins1_TSP(i,:),voisins1_Indexes(i,:),voisins1_Star(i,:),ring_costs,star_costs);
> ```

How would it be possible to avoid this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764062/optional-args-in-matlab-functions

Comment: @rafaelgonzalez Sorry, I don't understand well how this works... Could you explain about my situation, please ?

Comment: Not having any idea what your function `CalculCost` is doing with its input noone will be able to help you with your situation ... you just need to implement the idea in rafaels link ...

Comment: Avoid calling `voisins1_Star(i,:)` if the element does not exist. How you should implement it depends on your actual situation, but probably involves an if-test. Please always provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to post `CalculCost` to get a proper answer.

But going based on what you have posted, a solution to your problem is to make two functions, `CalculCost` and `CalculCostEmpty`, and put a check in the for loop:

```
for i=1:size(voisins1_TSP,1)
  if isempty(voisins1_TSP(i,:))
    cout(i)=CalculCostEmpty(voisins1_Indexes(i,:),voisins1_Star(i,:),ring_costs,star_costs);
  else
    cout(i)=CalculCost(voisins1_TSP(i,:),voisins1_Indexes(i,:),voisins1_Star(i,:),ring_costs,star_costs);
  end
end
```